# Need options to fix storage Issues on AWS EC2 instance with Darwin OS used by Jenkins Pipeline for ios Builds

Tags: ios, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, diskspace

I am trying to find ways to fix the issues with my EC2 instance having Darwin OS being used for the iOS builds by the Jenkins Pipeline.
We regularly run into storage issues due to the jenkins making use of one partition. How can we dynamically make use of the other partitions
The EC2 instance is used as an agent in the jenkins pipeline :

`agent { label env.AGENT_LABEL==null ? 'sharedios' : env.AGENT_LABEL }`

Below are the OS specification :

Darwin ip-172-27-5-60.eu-west-1.compute.internal 22.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.3.0: Mon Jan 30 20:42:11 PST 2023; root:xnu-8792.81.3~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Below is how the disk partition looks like:

`Filesystem       Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on /dev/disk2s4s1  100Gi  8.3Gi   19Gi    31%  349475 195107000    0%   / devfs           188Ki  188Ki    0Bi   100%     650         0  100%   /dev /dev/disk2s2    100Gi  1.7Gi   19Gi     9%     941 195107000    0%   /System/Volumes/Preboot /dev/disk2s6    100Gi   20Ki   19Gi     1%       0 195107000    0%   /System/Volumes/VM /dev/disk2s5    100Gi  476Ki   19Gi     1%      23 195107000    0%   /System/Volumes/Update /dev/disk2s1    100Gi   70Gi   19Gi    80% 3339801 195107000    2%   /System/Volumes/Data map auto_home     0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0         0  100%   /System/Volumes/Data/home`

- We have tried scheduling a cleanup job to free up some space by executing below command on the agent:
   `sh """ rm -rv /Users/ec2-user/jenkins- agent/51c710d5/workspace/T_PICCOLO_IOS_APP_piccolo_master/ios """`
- We also introduced a post build action to cleanup workspace as part of the pipeline :
   `cleanup { script { EventPublisher.instance.publish(PipelineEndEvent.create(this)) // cleanup workspace dir(env.WORKSPACE) { deleteDir() } } }`

DO we have some other solution to help fixing the storage issues apart from what we tried above.